# Golang Map-Reduce Master - Channels

Tags: go

The following code is taken from an archived course. Although my answer to the assignment passes  the tests, I'm not sure if it is actually the correct way to write golang code. Primarily because in my solution, there is one extra channel left at the end when the master node is done distributing map/reduce tasks. If it helps, the link to my code is https://github.com/tushar00jain/distribute/blob/master/mapreduce/master.go#L29

Although the code should be self explanatory, other definitions are in the same folder.

I have 2 solutions and I've provided one of them that uses channels below.

The `submitJob` function is responsible for making the map/reduce RPC call on the workers. If I interchange the lines marked as `replace`, the code does not work anymore, because there is no channel waiting for `mr.registerChannel` after the worker from the last job becomes available.

`mr.registerChannel` basically registers a worker (by sending the ip address) and indicates that it is available, so that a task waiting for this channel can execute. Once the task is done, it makes this channel available again. One thing to be noted is that, I other code will be sending on the `mr.registerChannel` as well (because there needs to be a worker to begin with).

The code after that just launches goroutines for all the map tasks, which wait for a worker to become available. Then I place blocking code with the `done` channel so that reduce only starts after all the maps are done. The code for reduce is also similar.

```
package mapreduce

import "container/list"
import "fmt"

func (mr *MapReduce) RunMaster() *list.List {
    // Your code here
    mr.Workers = make(map[string]*WorkerInfo)
    done := make(chan bool)

    var submitJob func(args *DoJobArgs)
    submitJob = func(args *DoJobArgs) {
        worker := <-mr.registerChannel
        if _, ok := mr.Workers[worker]; !ok {
            mr.Workers[worker] = &WorkerInfo{worker}
        }

        var res DoJobReply
        ok := call(worker, "Worker.DoJob", args, &res)
        if ok {
            done <- true                     // replace
            mr.registerChannel <- worker     // replace
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("DoJob: RPC %s Job error\n", worker)
            delete(mr.Workers, worker)
            // recursively keep trying with a different worker
            submitJob(args)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < mr.nMap; i++ {
            args := &DoJobArgs{mr.file, Map, i, mr.nReduce}
            go func(args *DoJobArgs) {
                submitJob(args)
            }(args)
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < mr.nMap; i++ {
        <-done
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < mr.nReduce; i++ {
            args := &DoJobArgs{mr.file, Reduce, i, mr.nMap}
            go func(args *DoJobArgs) {
                submitJob(args)
            }(args)         
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < mr.nReduce; i++ {
        <-done
    }

    close(done)
    return mr.KillWorkers()
}
```

Comment: The code in the question cannot be meaningfully reviewed without additional clarification, as `submitJob` doesn't seem to be working correctly (it tries to read from `mr.registerChannel` before anything gets written to it, resulting in a deadlock).